# How can I leverage browser caching for my shopify site?

Tags: caching, browser, shopify, pagespeed

I run novelteatins.com and though lately I've worked hard to make our imagery smaller etc, I still get some nastylooking errors when I test my site;

https://www.webpagetest.org/result/160817_H3_D50/1/performance_optimization/#cache_static_content

How can i actually 'Leverage browser caching of static assets' in Shopify? I'd really like to learn, but my searches just turns up more confused people, which makes me wonder if I'm asking the wrong question.

Thank you for any help!